# Heroku on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04

I am currently following 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial' by Michael Hartl. On Chapter 3 when I try to deploy the working sample app with Heroku it is rejected, and even though I fully understand the error message I do not know how to correct it. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And here is the file where the issue originates which is config/environments/development.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

The errors I get are attempting 'git push heroku master':

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for #<SampleApp::Application:0x007fc7f03f7298>
```

and after a long list of paths I get:

```
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:some-name.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:some-name.git'
```

Any idea how to fix this please? I really would like to get deployments working under Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails 4 will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into config/application.rb and add this line:

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

Have a read through this documentation on heroku as well - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was directed to that page before but it didn't work. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help. Have a look at my repo that I created recently and know that works on heroku -https://github.com/hsuh/nihongo . It is slightly different from Hartl tutorial because I'm trying to get Angularjs working on Heroku. Here's the working page - http://nameless-harbor-8868.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for the repo link, I'll look into that. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4**

The problem is a common issue with the `Hartl` tutorial - it derives from using `Rails 3` in the tutorial, and a later version being used widely now

I tried looking for references on this, but I couldn't. I've found them somewhere before - will have another look for you.

Anyway, in `Rails 4`, need this (we have this in our Rails 4 apps):

```
#config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
```

This sets the configure code block for the correct object. I think Rails changed some of its core functionality in 4.0+, which is why you're getting the issue now

Comment: Thank you too. I changed development.rb as suggested and that broke the ability to launch the server with 'rails s' so had to revert. I clearlyhave some version mix-up thing going on.